# OOP: class based and prototype based, are there other alternatives?

Tags: oop, programming-languages

I know of class-based and protype based object oriented programming languages, are there any other alternatives? What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are indeed the two main approaches behind object-oriented languages, and I'm not aware of another completely different underlying principle.

But there exists a **lot of variants** of both approaches, as well as a lot of **other programming language constructs** that tackles reuse/extensibility in either class-based or prototype-based language. Examples: traits, mixin, extension methods, partial class, generics, first-class slots, split objects, etc. A lot of such constructions are first proposed in research papers (ECOOP, OOPSLA, POPL conferences), and a few of them become mainstream in popular languages. But I would qualify them as *variations* and not as groundbreaking new underlying principle.

Note though than you can **mimic object-oriented programming** in languages which are not object-oriented *per-se*. For instance, with Clojure [multi-method](http://clojure.org/multimethods). Object-oriented and functional programming are also slowly merging, for instance in Scala.

**EDIT**

It's actually hard to make a list of classic/seminal papers, and I don't pretend to have sufficient knowledge to do so. If there is one somewhere, I would be very interested to see it :) Still, here are a few ones that might interest you.

Inheritance, delegation, subtyping:

- [Genericity vs inheritance](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=28738)
- [Inheritance Is Not Subtyping](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.102.8635&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [On the notion of inheritance](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=243441)
- [Split objects: a disciplined use of delegation within objects](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=236347)

Module, composition, adaptation

- [Traits: Composable Units of Behavior](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf)
- [Expanders: Statically Scoped Object Adaptation for Java](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~todd/research/expanders/)
- [JavaGI: Generalized Interfaces for Java](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/JavaGI/)

Comment: Hmm, I guess you are right, can you point me directly to some influential/good research papers? I will give you upvote straight for some links... I am aware of some of the functional stuff like in CLOS etc. I am interested in hearing more, therefore I asked this question:)

Answer (score 2):

mixins allow you to extend a class with code that is defined elsewhere, such as in a module.

See [Ruby Mixin Tutorial](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/) for an introduction.

Comment: how is it different from class based OOP with multiple inheritance (implementation without diamond problem)?

Comment: I agree it is very similar, however a mixin allows you to inject code from an "ancestor" without implying an *is a* relationship for the  descendant. Or in other words you could think of it as an interface that may also contain code.

Comment: ah, I understand, something like plicy based design in C++, where you would use traits to compose template class... if I understand it right, this violates Liskov Substitution principle right? Or is the "mixedIn" relationship explicitly different from inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

Go has a concept that is similar to classes, but without inheritance and with very flexible interfaces. You can read more about it in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#methods).

Comment: Hmm, this remainds me of something I heard about OOP in functional languages. Are there any requirements for a function adding to types interface/bahaviour? Does it have to be in same package at least?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Wikipedia's article on programming paradigms. The one I've worked with is aspect-oriented programming, which is where the mixins come in.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm

Comment: I read it and there is no further information regarding my question.